# Vertical centering of video elements in Mobile Safari iPad at "full screen"

Tags: html, css, ipad, html5-video, mobile-safari

I've had some trouble recently where a video element on my website wouldn't vertically center only on the iPad (iOS 8.3) mobile Safari at "full screen mode"(meaning a div that stretches across the entire window).

During the many trial and errors, I came across a peculiar behavior.  The video element vertically centers when the absolute positioned video is stretched to the full height and width and a margin auto is set:

edit: Please note that you need to decrease the width of the results section in the fiddle to view the effect.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p1p6s03r/)

HTML

```
<div class="hello">
  <video src="foo"></video>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.hello {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
video {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
}
```

This worked on mobile Safari and does not seem to have any adverse effects on Chrome Android or Firefox.  It also behaves as intended on desktop browsers as well. How is this margin vertically centering the video when I have fully stretched it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your fiddle isn't working without an actual video source. I could NOT reproduce the behaviour triggered by margins as you described it. but I did find you question on my own search for vertically centering the video on iOS. maybe my conclusion helps you:

The current iOS browser will leave empty space at the bottom of the video (assuming the video element is higher than it has to be to render the video as big as possible). the empty space at the bottom will as long as it's smaller than the size taken by the native controls. the obvious idea behind that being, not rendering the controls in front of the video but below it if possible.

here comes the catch: this will even happen if you deactivated the controls / did not activate them with the "controls" attribute. the only workaround I could come up with was getting the inherent width & height of the video and manually calculating the current actual video height. you could then go on and set the height to the video node and depending on your case also set a top-margin to vertically center it within your container.

hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned that you need to decrease the width of the results container in the fiddle in order to view the described results.  The reason the width needs to be decreased is to simulate a portrait mode of a device and it also more easily allows you to view the margin's effect.  Your answer finally let me figure out why the bottom margin was there for ios devices though.  Thank you!